# How to define a default parameter of Vector2f ? [SFML]

Tags: c++, sfml, build-error, default-parameters

I have some function func in a class `Class`:

```
 void func(int arg1, int arg2, Vector2f vec = Vector2f(0,0)){};
```

And I get a build error:

```
error C2572: 'Classs::func': redefinition of default argument: parameter 1
```

I tried many different synataxes but none worked. How can I define a default parameter of this type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the default parameter in the prototype only. Don't repeat this in the function definition.

```
// prototype
void func(int arg1, int arg2, Vector2f vec = Vector2f(0,0));

// definition
void func(int arg1, int arg2, Vector2f vec)
{
    ...
}
```

This advice applies to any default parameter. It's got nothing to do with the type.